Bound TypeVar resolution of arguments to multiplication
I am struggling with a problem of bound TypeVar resolution of function/method arguments.
Suppose I have a base class Base and a couple of derived classes. Also suppose I have a TypeVar T that is bound to Base. I want to define a generic container class that represents ordered "products" of such objects in form of a list[T].
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

class Base: ...


class X(Base): ...


class Y(Base): ...


class Z(Base): ...


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Base)


class Product(Generic[T]):

    objs: list[T]

    def __init__(self, objs: list[T]):
        self.objs = list(objs)


Such products can be

mixed: the list elements are instances of different subclasses of Base. The product is then Product[Base]
homogeneous: all list elements of the same type, e.g. Product[Y]

So far so good, the following works out and MyPy reveals the correct generic aliases
reveal_type(Product([X(), X()]))         # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"
reveal_type(Product([X(), X(), X()]))    # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"
reveal_type(Product([Y(), Y()]))         # note: Revealed type is "Product[Y]"
reveal_type(Product([X(), Y()]))         # note: Revealed type is "Product[Base]"
reveal_type(Product([X(), Y(), Z()]))    # note: Revealed type is "Product[Base]"

Especially in the mixed case, MyPy resolves T as the common superclass of the objs.
Now I want to be able to iteratively construct such products using the * operator, so I implement __mul__. There are three variants:

Base * Base -> Product
Base * Product -> Product
Product * Base -> Product (which I get with __rmul__ = __mul__)

class Base:
    def __mul__(self: T, other: T | Product[T]) -> Product[T]:
        if isinstance(other, Base):
            return Product([self, other])  # type: ignore[list-item]  # mypy expects T
        if isinstance(other, Product):
            return Product(other.objs + [self])
        return NotImplemented

    __rmul__ = __mul__

Now we have
reveal_type(X() * X())         # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"
reveal_type(X() * X() * X())   # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"
reveal_type(Y() * Y())         # note: Revealed type is "Product[Y]"
reveal_type(X() * Y())         # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"  # error: Unsupported operand types for * ("X" and "Y")  [operator]
reveal_type(X() * (Y() * Y())) # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"  # error: Unsupported operand types for * ("X" and "Product[Y]")  [operator]

So the homogeneous case works out, but the mixed case doesn't. The self parameter is evaluated first as X, before other is even taken into account. So MyPy does not resolve T as the common superclass of X and Y.
Interestingly, with a standalone function, this is different
def mult(a: T, b: T | Product[T]) -> Product[T]:
    if isinstance(b, Base):
        return Product([a, b])   # type: ignore[list-item]  # mypy expects T
    if isinstance(b, Product):
        return Product(b.objs + [a])
    raise NotImplementedError

Here I get

reveal_type(mult(X(), X()))             # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"
reveal_type(mult(X(), mult(X(), X())))  # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"
reveal_type(mult(Y(), Y()))             # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"
reveal_type(mult(X(), Y()))             # note: Revealed type is "Product[Base]"
reveal_type(mult(X(), mult(Y(), Y())))  # note: Revealed type is "Product[Any]"  # error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "mult"  [misc]

So in this case at least the mixed X * Y case works out, MyPy resolves T as the common superclass Base for X and Y. However the X * Product[Y] case again trips MyPy up, which I find strange, because the same T is involved.
What I want to achieve in the end is arbitrary sequences of multiplications that are inferred correctly by MyPy, e.g.
reveal_type(Y() * Y())        # note: Revealed type is "Product[Y]"
reveal_type(X() * X() * X())  # note: Revealed type is "Product[X]"
reveal_type(X() * Y() * Y())  # note: Revealed type is "Product[Base]"
reveal_type(X() * Y() * Z())  # note: Revealed type is "Product[Base]"

What is the best way to get this right? Is there a way?
I don't want to use specific overloads for all different combinations of X, Y, Z because in practice I have many more subclasses of Base and the number of overloads would explode.

Are you looking for this? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=93d347d1723575fbea404d2c09adaad8

Wow, yes, this is magic :-O I tried overloads but couldn't get it to work... would you mind turning that into an answer so I can accept?

@dROOOze would you happen to know how I can extend this to an inheritance tree with more levels, such that the multiplication output is always revealed as a Product of the closest common ancestor of the two things being multiplied? In your solution you manually set the top bound in case the two types differ, which is always correct, but too broad for my needs. I know mypy does this e.g. for lists. Is there a way to get this also for custom functions?

I'm afraid the API you have (using __mul__) prevents you from doing this. I think the reason is, self in __mul__ is strongly bound to the instance's class, so that any attempts in using a type variable on self solves for the instance type first, then raises an error because the other arguments aren't of the same type. If you use a free function, or an unrelated class like the Product's constructor, mypy solves for the common ancestor instead.

I see. That is unfortunate :-( Perhaps I can just implement a free function and assign it to __mul__, I'll try that
